# phpstorm javascript autoindent problem

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

writing a code block with auto indent. no manual tabbing...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#welc").toggle(function() {
            $(this).val("hello");
        }, function() {
                    $(this).val('hell');
                });
    });
</script>
```

got a result like that but it should be like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#welc").toggle(function() {
            $(this).val("hello");
        }, function() {
            $(this).val('hell');
        });
    });
</script>
```

a bug or i am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please [check this issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-70166). Should be addressed in 2.1.1 or next update.

Comment: CrazyCoder, also no auto-complete support for anonymous inside functions in jQuery so i need to close curly brackets my self. please look for this also.